# calculating variable in php not giving correct value

Tags: php, html, sql

i have a code which fetches value from database and subtracts to give a particular value. the values are coming from the database and there is no problem with that. the code is the following:

```html
    <del>
 <span class="amount">
  <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 
  <?php echo $getRowVenue['main_price_corporate_artist'];?>
 </span>
</del>
<span>( <b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 
<?php
 $strikePrice = $getRowVenue['main_price_corporate_artist'];
 $mainPrice = $getRowVenue['offer_price_corporate_artist'];

 echo $offer_price = $strikePrice - $mainPrice;


?> OFF</b> )
</span>
```

but when the substraction is done, its not giving me exact value , instead its giving me single digit values like the following:
[image]

how can i fix this?

Comment: What format is the data store in the DB?  If in a text format (or with the comma) the echo statement is essentially subtracting text from text.  Ensure the values are raw and then format them as currency after you have done your subtraction

Comment: @Will its in varchar format n database

Comment: how do i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the comma is not a valid character for 'standard' numbers, so PHP converts `13,000` to `13` and `10,000` to `10`.

You can use [numfmt_parse](https://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) to use your specific locale number format.

Comment: Good answer. Also worth mentioning that he probably should have used a numeric column type, and then formatting when outputting, using `number_format` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Please convert you prices from string with comma to float

```
$strikePrice = floatval(str_replace(',','.',$getRowVenue['main_price_corporate_artist']));

$mainPrice = floatval(str_replace(',','.',$getRowVenue['offer_price_corporate_artist']));
```

It should work